# How can i play mp4 videos on IOS devices using jwplayer

Tags: ios, jwplayer

I am trying to play mp4 videos in IOS devices. But i cant. Please guide me. I am new to programming.

Here is my code...

```
jwplayer('myElement').setup({
        file: "http://url",
        'width': '560',
        'height': '240',
        'file': '/music/audio.mp3',
        'controlbar': 'bottom'
    });
```

Comment: Any formate is fine for me(flash,html5). My goal is 'playing mp4 videos on IOS devices using JW player'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're giving it two different files, one an image and the other an audio file. You're using an attribute, controlbar, that doesn't exist in JW Player 6. Here are the JW Player embedding guidelines - if you don't see something listed there, it doesn't exist, and you can't just make things up:

http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1413113-configuration-options-reference

Now, for a simple example:

http://misterneutron.com/JW6video/

The "home" link on that page will take you to a collection of simple examples, which should help.

A properly-encoded MP4 will be playable virtually everywhere. The player will use HTML5 on all mobile devices (there's no Flash on a mobile) and on all current desktop browsers. Only IE8 and Firefox on WinXP will drop back to Flash, and WinXP is dead, at least in the eyes of MS.

Comment: I tried, those working fine in desktop and android devices. But, not working on IOS devices

Comment: Does a straight <video> tag work on your iOS device? If not, there's something wrong with your device. Try http://misterneutron.com/videoTag/

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
'file': '/music/audio.mp3',
```

To:

```
'type': 'mp4',
```

Since your mp4 file does not have an mp4 extension.